# Sum of all integers until input number and including input number in python

Tags: python, range

I am supposed to write code for the following problem.

Take a user input integer N, output the sum of all numbers from 1 to N, including end.

I kept trying using lists with ranges and ended up with the following

```py
n=int(input())
nums = range (0,n)
sum = sum(nums)
print(sum)
```

This gave me an error as n was not included in the sum. I simply edited the last line as `print(sum+n)` and got the correct answer.

```py
n=int(input())
nums = range (0,n)
sum = sum(nums)
print(sum+n)
```

But I have a feeling I just used a "shortcut" temporarily. I might have done something wrong though this code makes sense to me. Googling gives results for sum of two input integers, not for this problem.

Kindly help me understand what I did wrong and, if possible, why this worked.

I also tried shortening the code like this:

```py
n=int(input())
print(sum(range(0,n))+n)
```

This also got the correct answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you. The other comment explained range(1,n+1) should work. I understood now. Thanks a lot

Comment: BTW, don't use `sum` as a variable. After you do `sum = sum(nums)` you won't be able to call the `sum()` function again, because you've redefined it as the result of the first call.

Comment: Oh, ok. That makes sense. Thanks a lot for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the range function in python, the *stop* argument means that the loop will go up to but **will not include** *stop*, which in this context is *n*. Since you want to include *n*, you can set the *stop* argument as *n+1*.

Here is a more concise way to write the desired code:

```
def sum_numbers(n):
    return sum(range(1, n + 1))
```

that takes the argument *n*, and it returns the sum of all numbers from 1 to *n+1* (exclusive). Note that to print the output of this function, you can write `print(sum_numbers(n)` (replace n with desired integer number). This code avoids creating a list of numbers from 1 to n, it simply uses Python's built-in functions (range, sum) without relying on the intrinsic functionality of manual loops/iterations.